# get contacts / past mailed list vbs

Tags: email, vbscript

I have been trying to make a script that displays all the people I have ever emailed before and/or my contacts list.

I know how to send an email in vbs, but the code that I have for this task is for vb.net, and it does not work.

What I am looking for is the equivalent code in vbs.

```
        objEmail.From = "mailfrom"
        objEmail.To = "mailto"
        objEmail.Subject = "thisisasubject" 
        objEmail.Textbody = "Here is the message"
        objEmail.send
```

Comment: That code doesn't show any attempt to loop through contacts or sent emails. Are you trying to do this using Outlook? Take a look at the following: [VBA Script that gets list of Outlook Contacts using the Outlook Object Model](http://www.gregthatcher.com/Scripts/VBA/Outlook/GetListOfContacts.aspx)

Comment: For the second part of your question -- pertaining to vbs -- try adding this line to the beginning of your code example: `Dim objEmail : Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")`